# Mocking EF6 database context

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, entity-framework-6

I have a lot of instantiations of the DB context in my methods, like:

```
using (myEntities context = new myEnties())
    [do something with the context...]
}
```

I learn now, that my code is legacy code because it is lacking unit tests. To make my code testable, I would need to inject the context somehow, maybe via the constructor of the class. I would then maybe use Effort.EF6 or something to mock the context.

However, first I have to get away from constructing the context locally. But here is my question: when I started with EF a long time ago, I learned that it was a very good idea to have a short living context (while in the good old ADO days one would think twice about releasing a connection once established). Is it really a good idea to store the context in a field and not release it at all (a practice I saw even in MS code examples)? Does it release itself and "using" is not required?

On a side note: I could alternatively use integration tests and just provide the original connection and set up test data etc. I would then not need to refactor hundreds of "using" statements. This of course would slow the tests but it would also test my database (I am using a lot of stored procedures). Is this a feasible approach then?

Comment: How is your code structured? Do you have some kind of repository, service layer and UI pattern? Or just a bunch of instructions on the click handler of every button?

Comment: Integration test is the way to go. Mocking EF reliably is a dead end. Like getting a driver's license in a go-cart. Trying to separate business logic into data-layer-independent testable code is a better idea.

Comment: You can read this [article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1206737/In-memory-Entity-Framework-testing-via-Effort-libr), just for your situation, about testing against context with Effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can introduce a `ContextFactory` abstraction and keep hundreds of using statements and change only how context is initialized.

```
public interface IContextFactory
{
    DbContext Create();
}
```

And use it

```
using (var context = _contextFactory.Create())
{
    // Query staff
}
```

With approach above you will be able to provide mocked context to the code under the test or provide context connected to the test database for integration tests.

Suggest using some In-Memory database provider or SQLLite with in-memory mode for testing EF related logic as a black box. With context factory you will be able to pass required implementation of context to the code under the test.

Comment: So _contextFactory is a private property and the concrete factory that you would inject somehow, maybe via constructor? Looks good to me - is this a common technique?

Comment: This technique have name "Factory pattern" and I think it is common for the cases when you want move responsibility of creation to other classes/abstractions.

Comment: I picked this as the answer since it demonstrates a very simple method to keep the granular "using" statements while making it possible to mock the context (with Effort.EF6 for example).

Comment: The issue I'm experiencing with this approach is that my `context` object of type `DbContext` does not know about all the `DbSet`s my concrete `Context` object holds. So I cannot do smthg like `using (var context = _contextFactory.Create())
{ context.Users.First()}`.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest method I find to introduce unit testing to EF-related code that can be rolled out incrementally is to use a repository pattern. Often when you see examples of repositories you will see generic implementations, I.e. a repository per entity providing CRUD operations. Instead I favour using a repository per business area, think something along the lines of a repository per controller. (Not that specifically, but rather a repository serves a distinct area of the domain.)  The repositories are responsible for: Creating entities, Retrieving entities, and in the case of hard-deletes, Deleting entities. To get repositories to play nice with each other, and other code using DB Contexts you should also consider a unit of work pattern to wrap code in your controllers or service layer classes that will be interacting with a DbContext and Repositories. A really nice one I use regularly for EF is Mehdime DBContextScope.

With a unit of work like the DBContextScope, the repositories themselves are kept very lightweight where any method to retrieve data returns `IQueryable<TEntity>`, including when expected to be retrieving a single entity. Create methods are responsible for ensuring that code is passing all required data/references, and Delete methods ensure that EF cleans up orphaned records where needed.  By returning IQueryable you can avoid moving a lot of selection logic or decisions about what data to return into the repository as the calling code can do things like: .Include(), .Select(), .Any(), .Count(), etc. as appropriate to ensure that with deferred execution the queries executed are quite optimal.

This approach can be implemented alongside code using DbContexts, and the Repository implementations are easily mocked out. (I.e. return a list of stub entities, etc.)

Comment: Using IQueryble<TEntity> as return values seems like "Leaky abstraction" which expose implementation details. For example with IQueryble<TEntity> i will be able to write `repository.GetEntitties().Where(entity => MyMethod(entity))`. EF will not be able to "convert" my method to the sql query - so I need to be always aware of this even I writing business layer code.

Comment: I have not used a repository / unit of work pattern with EF at all. When I found it in legacy code I thought it was overly complicated. However, from the mentions in the answers here I may have to think that over.

Comment: I agree with you that is the best way to decouple and make it easier to test. Besides that i would also look at dependencie injection to make it even easier to test or change context.

Comment: @Fabio It's a trade-off. Yes, the calling code would need to respect that Entity Framework is the source of the IQueryable and use it accordingly, but the benefit is that you don't need heavyweight repositories or start returning back excessive data. Even just returning Entities at all is a form of leak. (I.e. dealing with lazy loading consequences and DbContext scope) Returning something like a POCO model/collection negates that, but leads to a lot of boilerplate code or returning far more data that is typically needed.

Comment: Usually you use DTO(data transfer objects) as input/output values for methods between layers. So you can fully separate business logic from database related dependencies

Comment: I've worked on many systems like that, and while it would be argued as better from a separation of concerns, it results in either far less efficient data access later (essentially doubling up your models (entity + DTO) or business logic dependencies leaking into your data layer. (lots of optimized calls in data later to return DTOs/results specific to each consumer) Your business logic already has a dependency on your data later to access the DBContext/Unit of Work, and the repository. A trade off for simpler, easily optimized code where business logic can consume entities as they see fit.

Answer (score 1):

The down side I see with a long lived context is that EF will track a lot of entities as u use them. And try to find what u are querying in memory before actually querying. And this of course takes longer as your in memory objects grow. But this depends what your requirements are. Sometimes its good to track the objects and reuse them from memory.

You could try to disable this with the following:

```
context.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;
```

But eventually it is a good practice to dispose the context. Although this will also happen when the garbage collectors see it without any references.

Comment: If the context is stored in a field than it will have a reference unless my instance of the class runs out of scope. One could then dispose the context in the destructor or just wait for the garbage collector. All that does not look as tidy as constructing and disposing the context with a granular "using" statement.